# Why doesn't my test that a share price is in a certain range work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numbers, range

I have a little code that doesn't work;

```
yahoo = Share('YHOO')
a = yahoo.get_price() #get price of stock
print "ok" if 45 <= a <= 50 else "no"
```

It is always printing "no" even when the stock price is 45.55

Comment: Yes, to make sure that a was 45.55

Comment: did you check that is of the correct type?

Comment: sorry i mistook that the stock price 45.55 was from some reports, not the actual value of a. i got ok when i tried python -c 'a=45.55;print "ok" if 45 <= a <= 50 else "no"' on commandline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using [yahoo-finance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance) (in which case, it would have been helpful to say so in your question), `Share.get_price()` [returns a string](https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance#get-shares-data):

> ```
> >>> from yahoo_finance import Share
> >>> yahoo = Share('YHOO')
> >>> print yahoo.get_open()
> '36.60'
> >>> print yahoo.get_price()
> '36.84'
> ```

So, you'll have to convert it to a `Decimal` object before doing any math or numeric comparison with it:

```
from decimal import Decimal

yahoo = Share('YHOO')
a = Decimal(yahoo.get_price())
print "ok" if 45 <= a <= 50 else "no"
```

`Decimal` is preferable to `float` if you're dealing with currency information, to avoid [rounding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Your solution works great. It all makes logical now (converting to decimal before comparing it with math). Also forget to mention the modules that I imported. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it may be the case that you get a string instead of a number

```
>>> a=45.55   #float
>>> 45 <= a <= 50
True
>>> a="45.55"  #string
>>> 45 <= a <= 50
False
>>>
```

to know the type do

```
>>> type("45.55")
<type 'str'>
>>> type(45.55)
<type 'float'>
>>>
```

for your code to work properly you need to get one of the numeric types `int`, `long` or `float` for the build-in, (also `Fraction` and `Decimal` build-in too, but you need to import them)

to fix your code just cast it to the correct numeric type like `float` or `Decimal`